# How to disable stories appearing in Messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger

In Messenger, you see those circles at the top which are your friends' stories. Is it possible to make those circles disappear for specific friends?

I know we have this:
[Hide someone's story on Messenger](https://facebook.com/help/messenger-app/409011672809505)

but I don't want to tap the story in the first place. Is there another way aside from this where you don't have to tap on the story?

Comment: Are you asking about the website (the only interface on topic here) or the app?